# Is there any relationship between confidence ratio in association rule and Bayesian rule?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, association-rules

I am currently studying Association Rule and somehow I thought about if there is any relationship between confidence ratio in Association Rule and Bayesian Rule. My knowledge in Bayesian Rule is not that deep and if you have any opinion, let me have some explanation about it.